# Explanation of Circuit?

Tags: arduino, relay, diy

Circuit for Time Controlled Switch

Can anyone please explain how this circuit is working? It is basically a time controlled switch? I want to know what is the functioning of each component i.e, resistor,transistor, etc?

What this circuit does is when we press the button, the appliance runs for the pre defined time which is in the coding.

[image: circuit]

Comment: What is pin2 and pin8?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: What parts of the circuit do you understand?

Comment: Like what is the functioning of transistor or the use the resistor?

Comment: Can anyone please explain how this circuit is working? It is basically a time controlled switch? I want to know what is the functioning of each component i.e, resistor,transistor, etc?

Comment: Pin 2 and Pin 8 are pins on the arduino uno board

Comment: I think you'd better learn the basics of electronic components instead of asking here how a circuit works. If you do a bit of reading first you'd know what a transistor does. This question is WAY too broad.

Comment: Unfortunately my glass orb is in service now and I can't foretell what's Your problem. Read http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask first and then ask concrete question, we're not diviners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pin 2 drives transistor T, which is used to drive the relay, which is used to connect the load to the return of the supply.

Basically, pin 2, enables or disables current flow in the load.

If I were to GUESS, I would think that when you press the button, the programming in the microcontroller sets pin 2...

When the button is released, clears pin 2.

This last part is a guess, because the schematic doesn't really say anything else.

Copied from the comments, and it may be correct given the basic text of the question.

> Seeing as it's called a "Time-controlled switch" I expect the user presses the button (and releases it) and the Arduino starts running a timer (or more likely, based on the poor quality of the design, a simple delay sequence) and then sets pin 2 low. – derstrom8

This is the best you are going to get with this limited information. Update body of the question with more than 5 words, and you may get a better answer.

Comment: What about Pin 8 and why the resistor?

Comment: Seeing as it's called a "Time-controlled switch" I expect the user presses the button (and releases it) and the Arduino starts running a timer (or more likely, based on the poor quality of the design, a simple delay sequence) and then sets pin 2 low.

Comment: @AshishSukhadeve do some research. This is a pathetic excuse for a question. Google "Pull-down resistor".

Comment: @derstrom8 You may be right. Missed the "Time-control" part.

Comment: Time Control is with the delay which is in programming

Comment: @AshishSukhadeve I shouldn't have even answered this question.  You question is so poor, that in my answer, I had to "guess". Change your question so its not vague, or risk it being closed.